# CSS stroke-width causing issues in Safari

Tags: html, css

I have a simple table html where I am trying to apply the `stroke-width` to the cells.  A simplified example appears here:

```css
td {
stroke: #5491CD;
stroke-width: 6px;
-webkit-clip-path: none opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
</table>
```

The issue is in Safari this appears to corrupt the text in the cell. Below is an screenshot of the issue for those that dont have Safari.

[image]

Comment: `stroke-width` is used for setting borders on svg shapes. I believe you should be looking at `border-width`.

Comment: This code was not originally coded by me so not sure why this was used.  Interesting that it causes corruption though.  It also appears to be inconsistent between different versions of Safari.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you're trying to set the `border` style?

```css
td {
  border: #5491CD solid 6px;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
</table>
```